# How to Removing Duplicate Values within String Which is inside Python Data-frame Cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, duplicates

I have the following Dataframe

[image]

If you look at the first row, the string consists of duplicate values; Ex GM0001, GMM003 and so on.

Is it possible to remove those duplicates within each Cell in SITE_ID column ??

Comment: Is `SITE_ID` a tuple or a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn the tuples into sets:

```
df['SITE_ID_UNIQUE'] = df.SITE_ID.apply(set)
```

Answer (score 1):

Vinura Perera answer works just fine... provided you are okay with the brackets instead of tuples. It also adds another column to your dataframe. If you need tuples and don't want to create another column try this:

```
df['SITE'] = [str(set(i)).replace('{', '(').replace('}', ')') for i in df['SITE']]
```